# SQL - Find users who never logged in for two weeks or more

Tags: sql

```
Date        UserID  
1/1/2013    Jo1234   
2/1/2013    Bob1234    
2/2/2013    Bob1234    
2/3/2013    Cal5678  
1/4/2013    Bob1234   
2/1/2013    Bob1234    
2/2/2013    Bob1234    
2/3/2013    Cal5678
```

Hi
I would like to find the users who didn't log in for two weeks or more

```
SELECT DISTINCT [UserID]  FROM UsersTable
```

I cant use `WEEK()` as I am using an older version of sql
I appreciate your help

Comment: Exactly which version of SQL are you using? Are you referring to a week as 7 days ago or calendar week?

Comment: A calendar week.

Comment: When I use WEEK() >> week is not a recognized built in function name. sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to filter based on two weeks (14 days), you can use the following to filter the results out :

```
DATEADD(DAY, -14, GETDATE()
```

Consider the following dataset :

```
CREATE TABLE Test(LastDateOfLogin DATE, UserID  NVARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO Test VALUES('11-Nov-2020', 'Jo1234')
INSERT INTO Test VALUES('01-Nov-2020', 'Bob1234')
INSERT INTO Test VALUES('02-Nov-2020', 'Bob1234')
INSERT INTO Test VALUES('03-Nov-2020', 'Cal5678')
INSERT INTO Test VALUES('03-Nov-2020', 'Bob1234')
INSERT INTO Test VALUES('12-Nov-2020', 'Bob1234')
INSERT INTO Test VALUES('15-Nov-2020', 'Bob1234')
INSERT INTO Test VALUES('05-Nov-2020', 'Cal5678')
```

The table will look as :

[image]

Write the  query :

```
SELECT      LastDateOfLogin, UserID
FROM        Test
WHERE       LastDateOfLogin <= DATEADD(DAY, - 14, GETDATE())
```

The result will be :

[image]

Hope, this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT [UserID]  FROM UsersTable WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, myDateCol, getDate()) >= 14

Basic date functions are easily found for SQL Server; please check Google for date calculations if you need something more precise.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

To answer your part about WEEK(), you are correct. No such thing exists. You have to use DATEPART().

```
SELECT DATEPART(WW, GETDATE());
```

I think what you are looking for though is

```
SELECT DISTINCT [UserID] 
FROM UsersTable
GROUP BY [UserID]
HAVING MAX(Date) < CAST(DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
```